# How would I send a message to all discord servers my bot is in v14 discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to get help with making code so that I can send a message to all servers when I want too? All the previous posts are discord.py or older versions of discord.js

Comment: This is highly unrecommended. It's API spam. A better alternative is to use an announcement channel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant "all channels on all servers", you can recurse [`Client#channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager).

```
client.channels.cache.forEach(ch => ch.send("message"));
```

If you meant "specified channel(s) on all servers", use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before forEach.

Comment: I was more meaning that the bot sends in a random channel

Comment: You can use Collection#random https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=random.